# How to export model's mesh with adjacency information

Tags: export

I am working on raytraced engine, for faster ray queries I need my exported models contain information on their triangle's adjacency. How can I export my models along with triangle(face) adjacency information? *i.e. triangle 5 is neighbour of triangles 2, 6 and 8.*

Comment: Theres nothing really Blender specific here, the question is really about data-structures.